# MYSQL How to check if table has NULL, not 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query to select the rows from my table that have NULL value. However, it keeps selecting the rows that have  0 in them as well. I can't figure out what to do to get it so it only looks for the word 'NULL'.

```
SELECT *
FROM adult4
WHERE '?' IN (workclass, education, maritalstatus, occupation, relationship,
  race, sex, nativecountry) OR NULL IN (age, fnlwgt, educationnum, 
  capitalgain, capitalloss, hoursperweek);
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: if you're using mysql you can use `where cell is null`. Note that you generally want to check for the value `null` and not the string `'null'`

Comment: A few questions: 1. Are you looking for null values or the word "NULL"?  2. You have two where clauses with an OR between them, so could the rows with 0 in them be because there was a "?" in one of the other fields? 3. Can you give some examples of rows that are being returned that you didn't expect to be returned?

Comment: `'NULL'` <> `NULL` is your issue. NULL is the absence of data. 'NULL' is the string literal for the word "NULL". `IS NULL` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @Jens I'm new to this so i'm not too sure but I am using PuTTY.

Comment: @user4343563 PUTY is not a DBMS. DBMS are `MySQL, `SQL-Server`...

Comment: I put NULL in quotations since when I put it by itself it was returning the rows with 0 so I had hoped that if it was searching for that specific string it would only look for the word NULL but it still didn't work

Comment: @Jens i'm using mysql

Comment: PuTTY is just an ssh client, if you don't know then it's probably mysql, you can check by doing this terminal command `mysql --version mysql`

Comment: you can use `isNull()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a value is `null` you can use tthe `isNull()` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM adult4
WHERE isNull(age) or isNull(fnlwgt) ...
```

For more Information see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: I used a variation of this and got it to work. Instead of isNULL(age) I did WHERE age IS NULL OR ... Thanks!